# SQL com PHP - Problema no SELECT

Tags: php, sql

Tenho um álbum, assim que clico no álbum, é para aparecer somente as fotos que estejam no banco de dados com o id do álbum selecionado, clico no álbum e esta vindo as fotos do álbum com o id selecionado e o id do outro álbum também, vem todas as fotos em 1 álbum só, meu select está assim:

```
select fotos.*, albuns.album_name from fotos 
INNER JOIN albuns ON fotos.foto_album = albuns.album_id
```

pego a variavel do album_id pelo get da pagina:

```
$album_id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Interessante que você nem usa a variável `$album_id` na cláusula SQL. Não deveria existir uma instrução **where** ali indicando o `id` do álbum?

Comment: Isso mesmo, certinho agora, funcionou, obrigado !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você deve utilizar o `WHERE`.

```
SELECT fotos.*, 
       albuns.album_name 
FROM   fotos 
       INNER JOIN albuns 
               ON fotos.foto_album = albuns.album_id 
WHERE  albuns.album_id = 123456
```

Neste caso `123456` é o `$album_id`, por exemplo:

```
$album_id = mysqli_real_escape_string($sql, $_GET['id']);

mysqli_query($sql, '    
    SELECT fotos.*, 
           albuns.album_name 
    FROM   fotos 
           INNER JOIN albuns 
                   ON fotos.foto_album = albuns.album_id 
    WHERE  albuns.album_id = "'.$album_id.'"
');
```

O `WHERE` irá apenas obter os dados onde o `album_id` do `albuns` for igual ao valor do `$album_id`.

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente !